# What is the maximum number of dice you can roll in Arkham Horror 2nd Edition?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-dunwich-horror, arkham-horror-innsmouth-horror, arkham-horror-miskatonic-horror, arkham-horror-kingsport-horror

I have the complete set of Arkham Horror 2e, including all the expansions.  I'm now wanting to get some custom dice for AH, and I'd like to know what the max number of dice needed is to be able to make a single roll no matter the situation.  Does anybody have any ideas what this would be?  Someone mentioned a situation where a player would roll 13 dice, but it was an example, not a limit.  That's the highest I've seen so far though...

Comment: I've seen 18 fwiw.  Since I saw 13 myself I started keeping track;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum number of dice you can roll - it is infinite as the rules never explicitly call out a maximum dice total.

Considering the mechanics of the game though the extreme theoretical limit would be somewhere over 70 (but likely less than 80).

**In theory....**

I don't have the time to go through every card to work it out, but given the example from the rulebook as a basis where Ashcan Pete has 16 dice (it was 13 after accounting for the monster he was facing), we could easily add a further 2 by replacing his .45 Automatic with another copy of Shrivelling, bringing us to 18.

We then account for the fact there should be 48 Clue tokens in the game according to the rulebook (extremely unlikely a player could ever get all of them, but we are talking pure theory here), we are up to 66 dice.

Then considering a few monsters give a positive combat modifier, and some skills give further bonuses, and (it's been a long time so I don't quite remember) there may be character abilities that can add a few more points (situationally or by spending resources), we could push past 70 dice for a single combat roll.

**In actuality....**

Around 15 dice will do in most real cases, and any player who does stack up a larger hit has the satisfaction of rolling multiple handfuls of dice (and the pain of keeping a running tally if they really want to roll all of them).

My personal copy of the game has 30+ dice, but that is more for spreading them around the table within easy reach of all players, than in the expectation of a massive roll.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. Given the idea of 15, I'm thinking then that around 30 would allow most cases to not have to multiple roll the same die, while also lowering the instances of needing to pass dice around as much.  Thanks again!

Comment: @KevenM please consider accepting the answer if you're satisfied.  It gives both you and the answerer rep and closes the question.

Comment: For fun, Voice of Ra gives you +1 to all checks and as far as I know stacks, so you could probably get 4 more from 4 successful castings.  +1 for fun theoretical then actual answer.

Comment: I'm normally really good about accepting, I must have missed it this time.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Clue tokens allow you to roll additional dice one at a time. At no point that I see do the rules permit you to roll multiple dice at once from clue tokens. (rules page 13): "A player may
spend Clue tokens, one at a time, after any skill check
(failed or not)." So, you dont need nearly +48 dice to execute such a scenario unless you insist on keeping your failed dice around until you finish your skill check, or have a check needing an absurd number of successes. Or perhaps if you permit rolling multiple dice at once from clues as a shortcut (which just sounds like poor strategy anyway)

Comment: @Matt The rules as you point out say `failed or not` so a player could (for some strange reason) intend to use every Clue token they have regardless of the outcome of the roll. It would be incredibly silly in such a situation to roll one at a time.

Comment: Yes, I guess they do. I'm not sure how I missed that possibility. Although I don't believe the rules say you must keep successes around until the skill check is complete either. But thats how I always play since it makes keeping track easier.

Comment: Also the 70+ dice is just a crazy theoretical limit - it was intended as an exercise in the limits of the game, not as an indicator of what could happen or is likely to ever happen.